# Tag synonyms for denial-of-service

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Since [the DOS tag is ambiguous](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4969/the-dos-tag-is-ambiguous), I've just created the [denial-of-service](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service) tag. I already started retagging a few questions.

The problem is that [denial-of-service](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service) won't appear as a possible choice when somebody starts typing `dos` (or `ddos`) in the "Tags" field.

To fix this, I'd like these two tag synonyms to be created:

[ddos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ddos), [dos-attack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dos-attack) -> [denial-of-service](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ddos makes sense to remap to denial-of-service but dos-attack does not since it no longer is called up by the system and by the time you've typed up dos you should see ddos which is now denial-of-service which brings you to the start again.

Comment: `[dos-attack]` never existed; I just wanted a shortcut to the new tag. But you're right: `[ddos]` already achieves that.